# edit community page style from lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, style

I want to change the background of the page with title ='Home' for example,
and I want to do it by lightning component.

I know that the Id of the page is `NapiliCommunityTemplate` ,

how to do this? can I reach the page style from the component?, or is there another way to do it.

Note: community is single page application so by builder I can set style which applied to all pages but not to specific one.

I tried this:

```
if(document.title.indexOf("Home")>=0)
        {
            alert(document.title); 

            var divx = document.getElementById('NapiliCommunityTemplate');// this return null
            divx.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Not FOund");                     
        }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [Custom Theme Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm) and apply it to the Home Page through the Page Properties:

[image]

Under Layout > Theme Layout Type:

[image]

Comment: thanks for you answer.. I think its correct and I will try ... but why css condition does not work with community ?